# How to get count based on Id

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, stored-procedures, count

In my stored procedure, I have a tempory table `@Branches`. I am inserting values into `@Branches` and table structure is as follows:

```
declare @Branches table( BranchId int, BranchName varchar(60))

BranchID    BranchName  IsActive
--------------------------------
16          New Delhi       1
17          Panjab          0
```

In my database have a table called `lobby` and its data as follows,

```
QueueID FkBranch    IsActive    Status  AddedLocalTime  FkAssistTypeID
553279  16              1           5   7/12/2019           2
553278  16              1           5   7/12/2019           1
553277  16              1           5   7/12/2019           1
553276  16              1           5   7/12/2019           1
553275  16              1           5   7/12/2019           2
553274  16              1           5   7/9/2019            2
```

I need to get count of the `FkAssistTypeID` based on its value, I retied this Script

```
declare @BranchDetail table (Id int, Name varchar(60), TotalInteraction float, AssistCount float)

insert into @BranchDetail
    select b.BranchId as Id, b.BranchName as Name, 
    count(lo.LobbyId) TotalInteraction,
    count(case WHEN lo.FkAssistTypeID = 1 then 1 end) as AssistCount
from 
    @Branches b
left outer join
    (select br.BranchId, l.LobbyId, l.FkAssistTypeID
     from lobby l 
     left outer join @Branches br on l.FkBranchId = br.BranchId
     where l.AddedLocalTime >= @startDate 
       and l.AddedLocalTime <= CONVERT(VARCHAR, @endDate, 101) + ' 23:59:59'
       and l.IsActive = 1 
    group by br.BranchId, l.LobbyId) lo on lo.BranchId = b.BranchId 
group by 
    b.BranchId, b.BranchName
order by 
    b.BranchName

select @AvgInteractions= COALESCE( Convert(decimal(18,2), AVG(TotalInteraction)),0) from @BranchDetail

update @BranchDetail
SET AverageInteractions =@AvgInteractions from @BranchDetail

select * from @BranchDetail
```

I'm getting this error

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spGetActComDetails, Line 228 [Batch Start Line 7]
>   Column 'lobby.FkAssistTypeId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

But If I remove `FkAssistTypeID` everywhere its used in the above query, query works fine and retreive this output.

[image]

But I need this

[image]

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
insert into @BranchDetail
select b.BranchId as Id,b.BranchName as Name,count(lo.LobbyId) TotalInteraction,
SUM(case WHEN lo.FkAssistTypeID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as AssistCount
from @Branches b
left outer join
(
select  br.BranchId,l.LobbyId,l.FkAssistTypeID
from lobby l 
left outer join @Branches br on l.FkBranchId=br.BranchId
where  l.AddedLocalTime >=@startDate and ( l.AddedLocalTime ) <= CONVERT(VARCHAR, @endDate, 101)+ ' 23:59:59'and l.IsActive=1
group by br.BranchId,l.LobbyId,l.FkAssistTypeID) lo on lo.BranchId=b.BranchId 
group by b.BranchId,b.BranchName
order by b.BranchName
```

You need to use `SUM` instead `COUNT`, because [COUNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> COUNT(*) returns the number of items in a group. This includes NULL
>   values and duplicates.

Comment: @Adam Can you try now? I have added the column to the `group by` statement (the inner one)

Comment: Thanks its works now, May I now can I use the other column same as this rather than Id columns(int values)

Comment: In your internal statement you can use `DISTINCT` to get unique values - there is no need to perform `GROUP BY` over all selected columns.